# How can we keep our tasks accessible to view and report on while not having them count against the data storage limit?

Tags: limits, tasks, database, data-storage

The org I am working with right now is using 210% of its allotted data storage. Most of the storage space is taken up by tasks (over 31M records). Is there a way to decrease the data usage while keeping those tasks accessible (without buying more storage)? Here are some of the options I have thought of, but I don't know enough to decide if any of them are viable:

1. since the org’s data gets backed up daily via an Oracle database, maybe there’s a way to have only the tasks for the last three months displayed on objects (so only those would be stored in Sf), and have a custom button/link that would allow to load more from the database on demand;
2. perhaps there’s a third-party tool that would allow for a similar functionality;
3. maybe storing those Tasks with Heroku/Amazon Web Services and pulling in into Sf via code would be the best option.

The important part is that those tasks don’t need to be merely exported and stored somewhere, but must have the ability to be pulled up quickly on demand.

I have been looking into External Objects/Lightning Connect, but those don't allow for reporting, and that's an important feature for us to have for those Tasks.

If anyone has any ideas/experiences to share, I would appreciate it greatly. Thank you!

Comment: You list a bunch of good options, all of which seem viable. I don't have a lot of experience in this arena, but it seems like pulling from the Oracle database as you need would be the path of least resistance, since the data already lives there.